# How to git diff between branches in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branch, diff

It is trivial to diff between two files that are on the same branch/commit but how do you diff between different branches? I read this:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_viewing-diffs

Answer (score 3):

You can set vscode as git diff tool:

```
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

Then run `git difftool one_branch two_branch` to show diff in vscode.

Alternatively, install an extension, e.g. Git History (donjayamanne.githistory)